# Error in evaluating root project in android studio

Tags: android

Error:(19) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'speech-android-sdk-master'.

> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_aqyn7a203grykxpxh7k62duaz$_run_closure2@48b6a286] on root project 'speech-android-sdk-master'.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuilt a project. Can you paste your full logcat for more detail.

Comment: DEPRECATED - Please use https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk